# What's the best way to see accident rates for a particular make/model of aircraft?

Tags: ntsb

I'm looking for a simple way to get NTSB safety statistics for different makes/models of aircraft so I can answer questions like:

- How does the Diamond Aircraft safety record compare to general aviation over the last 5 years? All time?
- How does does the Diamond Aircraft DA42 safety record compare to general aviation?
- What were the (statistically significant) safest aircrafts in general aviation over the prior 5 years? What were the safest jets?

These are *examples* of questions. I'm mostly wondering if there is a tool or website out there that can help you answer these sorts of questions, or help visualize the NTSB data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can search the NTSB's accident database here:

https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx

Results can be filtered by date, aircraft type, location, etc.

Another good reference source would be the General Aviation Manufacturer's Association.

https://gama.aero/

Their annual report publishes accident data on general aviation aircraft.  The organization may be contacted for further information on this subject.

https://gama.aero/wp-content/uploads/2016-GAMA-Databook_forWeb.pdf

Comment: Thx for the response! It doesn't look like the NTSB site gives you statistics on the accident rates through that query engine, just a list of accidents? I believe it could be calculated by doing the work in excel, but I was hoping someone had taken the time to generate some more accessible data visualization from it.

Comment: You might try here as well https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?AcType=DA42